# Able to search document with Name but not with metadata

Tags: sharepoint-search

I am in a very strange situation. Currently we have a document library and we are searching document in it. When we are searching with name I can see the document coming in search result but when we try with ManagedProperty its not working.

I also check the crawl log and see the document and does not have any error. I am not sure what is going wrong. This is happening with some of the documents in library not with all.

We have continues crawl setup up.

When we did full crawl, we forgot to create crawl property so we created crawl property after full crawl. We did reset re-index document library after creation of managed property. This option is available in Library Settings -> Advanced Settings.

Because we have setup continues crawl it picked up some of the documents but strangely i am not able to search with metadata for all documents.

So do we have to do full crawl if we create managed property when incremental crawl is on?